# Issues with dynamic widget in theme customizer

Tags: themes, theme-customizer

I am trying to create custom widgets with repeater fields that can be dragged to reorder. I have them working correctly in the widgets screen, but in the theme customizer they do not work as intended.

The repeated fields do not update as you are typing or reorder them, sometimes the apply button will pop up and other times it wont. Sometimes the save button pops up within the repeated fields which if clicked reloads the page.

So what I am trying to accomplish is to get the widget to automatically update in customizer as changes are made but I am at a loss. Any ideas what I am missing?

I have also uploaded the theme to http://adonis.design/widget-test.zip if you would like to test it out to see it first hand.

The Widget Code

```
<?php
/*
    Features Widget
*/

class widgettest_widget_features extends WP_Widget {

    // Sets up a new features widget.
        public function __construct() {
            $widget_ops = [
                'classname' => 'features alt',
                'description' => __( 'Features widget designed for use in the Homepage widget area.', 'widgettest' ),
                'customize_selective_refresh' => true,
            ];
            parent::__construct( 'widgettest-features', __( '(widgettest) Homepage Features', 'widgettest' ), $widget_ops );
        }

    // Outputs the content for the current features widget.
        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

            // Set the widget ID.
                if ( ! isset( $args['widget_id'] ) ) {
                    $args['widget_id'] = $this->id;
                }

            // Vars.
                $title          = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? $instance['title'] : '';
                $title          = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );
                $widget_text    = ! empty( $instance['text'] ) ? $instance['text'] : '';
                $text           = apply_filters( 'widget_text', $widget_text, $instance, $this );
                $methods        = isset( $instance['methods'] ) ? $instance['methods'] : '';

            // Show features widget if enabled.        

                if ( is_active_widget( false, false, $this->id_base, true ) ) {

                    // Print Blurb.

                        if ( $title || $text )
                            echo '<section>';

                        if ( $title )
                            echo '<h1>' . $title . '</h1>';

                        if ( $text )
                            echo '<p>' . $text . '</p>';

                        if ( $title || $text )                
                            echo '</section>';

                    // Print Features.
                        echo '<section class="features alt">';

                        if ( !empty( $methods ) ) {
                            foreach ( $methods as $method_source ) {

                                if ( !empty( $method_source['icon'] ) )
                                    $icon = $method_source['icon'];
                                else
                                    $icon = 'diamond';

                                echo '<article class="icon fa-' . $icon . '">';

                                     if ( !empty( $method_source['title'] ) )
                                         echo '<h3>' . $method_source['title'] . '</h3>';
                                    else
                                        echo '<h3>' . __( '(no title)', 'widgettest' ) . '</h3>';

                                     if ( !empty( $method_source['description'] ) )
                                          echo '<p>' . $method_source['description'] . '</p>';
                                     else
                                          echo '<p>' . __( '(no description)', 'widgettest' ) . '</p>';

                                echo '</article>';

                            }
                        } else {
                            echo '<p>' . __( '(no features)', 'widgettest' ) . '</p>';
                        }
                        echo '</section>';

                } else {

                    if ( get_theme_mod( 'show_demo_content' ) )
                        widgettest_features_default();

                }    

    }

    // Handles updating the settings for the current Featured Posts widget instance.
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {

            // Vars.
                $instance               = $old_instance;
                $instance['title']      = sanitize_text_field( $new_instance['title'] );
                $instance['methods']    = [];

                if ( current_user_can( 'unfiltered_html' ) )
                    $instance['text']   = $new_instance['text'];
                else
                    $instance['text']   = wp_kses_post( $new_instance['text'] );             

            // Allowed HTML tags.
                $allowed_tags           = [ 'br' => [] ];

            // Save widget data.
                if ( isset( $new_instance['methods'] ) ) {
                    foreach ( $new_instance['methods'] as $method_source )
                        $instance['methods'][] = wp_kses( $method_source, $allowed_tags );
                }

            return $instance;
        }   

    // Outputs the settings form for the features widget.
        public function form( $instance ) {

            $instance                   = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '', 'text' => '' ) );
            $title                      = sanitize_text_field( $instance['title'] );
            $methods                    = isset( $instance['methods'] ) ? $instance['methods'] : [];
            $method_num                 = count( $methods );
            $methods[$method_num + 1]   = '';
            $methods_html               = [];
            $method_counter             = 0;     

            echo '
                <div>
                    <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) . '">' . __( 'Title:', 'widgettest' ) . '</label>
                    <input class="widefat" id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'title' ) . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) . '" type="text" value="' . $title . '" placeholder="' . __('eg. Lorem Ipsum Dolor', 'widgettest' ) . '" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="' . $this->get_field_id( 'text' ) . '">' . __( 'Content:' ) . '</label>
                    <textarea class="widefat" rows="8" cols="20" id="' . $this->get_field_id('text') . '" name="' . $this->get_field_name('text') . '" placeholder="' . __('eg. Nullam et nibh eleifend, pharetra urna id, tempor odio. Integer dapibus odio sit amet risus blandit scelerisque eget in est.', 'widgettest' ) . '" >' . esc_textarea( $instance['text'] ) . '</textarea>
                </div>
            ';

            foreach ( $methods as $method_source ) {
                if ( isset( $method_source['title'] ) ) {

                    $title = !empty( $method_source['title'] ) ? $method_source['title'] : __( '(no title)', 'widgettest' );                 

                    $methods_html[] =
                        '<div class="contact_method widget_toggle">
                            <header>
                                <h4>' . esc_attr( $title ) . '</h4>
                            </header>
                            <div class="inner">
                        ' .
                        sprintf(
                            '
                            <div>
                                 <label>%1$s</label>
                                 <input type="text" name="%2$s[%3$s][%4$s]" value="%5$s" placeholder="%7$s" class="widefat" /><br />
                                 <small>%6$s <a href="http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/">Font Awesome Cheatsheet</a></small>
                            </div>
                            ',
                            __( 'Icon:', 'widgettest' ),                           // Label
                            $this->get_field_name( 'methods' ),                 // Field Name
                            $method_counter,                                    // Counter
                            'icon',                                             // Field Option
                            esc_attr( $method_source['icon'] ),                 // Field Value
                            __( 'Enter the icon name without the fa- prefix. Icon names can be found at', 'widgettest' ), // Text Label
                            __( 'eg. twitter', 'widgettest' )
                        )
                        .
                        sprintf(
                            '
                            <div>
                                <label>%1$s</label>
                                <input type="text" name="%2$s[%3$s][%4$s]" value="%5$s" class="widefat" placeholder="%7$s" />
                                <small>&lt;br /&gt; %6$s</small>
                            </div>
                            ',
                            __( 'Title:', 'widgettest' ),                     // Label
                            $this->get_field_name( 'methods' ),                 // Field Name
                            $method_counter,                                    // Counter
                            'title',                                            // Field Option
                            esc_attr( $method_source['title'] ),                // Field Value
                            __( 'tags are allowed.', 'widgettest' ),               // Text Label
                            __( 'eg. twitter', 'widgettest' )
                        )
                        .
                        sprintf(
                            '
                            <div>
                                <label>%1$s</label>
                                <input type="text" name="%2$s[%3$s][%4$s]" value="%5$s" class="widefat" placeholder="%7$s" />
                            </div>
                            <span class="remove-field button button-large">%6$s</span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            ',
                            __( 'Description:', 'widgettest' ),                    // Label
                            $this->get_field_name( 'methods' ),                 // Field Name
                            $method_counter,                                    // Counter
                            'description',                                      // Field Option
                            esc_attr( $method_source['description'] ),          // Field Value         
                            __( 'Delete Feature', 'widgettest' ),                  // Button Text
                            __( 'eg. Duis non efficitur nisi, sed justo. Maecenas sagittis semper.', 'widgettest' )
                        );               
                }
                $method_counter++;

            }

            echo '
                <h4>' . __( 'Features:', 'widgettest' ) . '</h4>
                <div class="widget_sort">
            ';           

            print join( $methods_html );

            echo '
                </div>
                <span id="' . $this->get_field_id( 'field_clone' ) . '"></span>
                <div>
                    <input class="button ' . $this->get_field_id( 'add_field' ) . ' button-primary button-large" type="button" value="' . __( 'Add Feature', 'widgettest' ) . '"  />
                </div>
            ';

            ?> 

            <script type="text/javascript">

                jQuery(function($) {

                    var field       = <?php echo json_encode( $this->get_field_name('methods') ) ?>,
                        fieldnum    = <?php echo json_encode( $method_counter-1 ) ?>,
                        count       = fieldnum;                  

                    // Duplicate Fields
                        jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'add_field' ); ?>', function(event) {

                            console.log('click');

                            event.stopImmediatePropagation();

                            var clone_fields = '\
                                <div class="contact_method widget_toggle unsaved">\
                                    <header class="active">\
                                        <h4><a href="#"><?php _e( "Add Feature", "widgettest" ); ?></a></h4>\
                                    </header>\
                                    <div class="inner active">\
                                        <div>\
                                            <label><?php _e( "Icon:", "widgettest" ); ?></label>\
                                            <input type="text" name="' + field + '[' + (count) + '][icon]" value="" placeholder="<?php _e( "eg. twitter", "widgettest" ) ?>" class="widefat" /><br />\
                                            <small>\
                                                <?php _e( "Enter the icon name without the fa- prefix. Icon names can be found at", "widgettest" ); ?>\
                                                <a href="http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/">Font Awesome Cheatsheet</a>\
                                            </small>\
                                        </div>\
                                        <div>\
                                            <label><?php _e( "Title:", "widgettest" ); ?></label>\
                                            <input type="text" name="' + field + '[' + (count) + '][title]" value="" class="widefat" placeholder="<?php _e( "eg. twitter", "widgettest" ) ?>" />\
                                        </div>\
                                        <div>\
                                            <label><?php _e( "Description:", "widgettest" ); ?></label>\
                                            <input type="text" name="' + field + '[' + (count) + '][description]" value="" class="widefat" placeholder="<?php _e( "eg. Duis non efficitur nisi, sed justo. Maecenas sagittis semper.", "widgettest" ) ?>" />\
                                        </div>\
                                        <footer>\
                                            <input name="savewidget" id="' + field + '-' + count + '-savewidget" class="button button-large button-primary widget-control-save" value="<?php _e( "Save", "widgettest" ); ?>" type="submit">\
                                            <span class="remove-field button button-large"><?php _e( "Cancel", "widgettest" ); ?></span>\
                                        </footer>\
                                    </div>\
                                </div>\
                            ';

                            $( '#<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'field_clone' );?>' ).append( clone_fields );

                            count++;

                    });

                    // Remove Fields
                        jQuery( document ).on( 'click', '.remove-field', function() {
                            jQuery( this ).closest('.contact_method').remove();
                        });  

                });
            </script>

            <?php 

        }

} 
add_action( 'widgets_init', create_function( '', 'return register_widget( "widgettest_widget_features" );' ) );

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Default widget data
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function widgettest_features_default() {

     echo '
         <!-- Blurb -->
                <section>
                    <h1>' . __( 'Home Page Features Widget', 'widgettest' ) . '</h1>
                    <p>' . __( 'You can hide this section by go to Appearance / Customize / widgettest Settings in the wp-admin. If you would like to use this section go to Appearance / Widgets and drag the <strong>widgettest: Features</strong> widget to the Homepage sidebar and enter your information.', 'widgettest' ) . '</p>
                </section>

            <!-- Features -->
                <section class="features alt">
                    <article class="icon fa-diamond">
                        <h3>Nisl sed vitae</h3>
                        <p>Nullam et orci sed lorem magna et vivamus sagittis libero.</p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="icon fa-floppy-o">
                        <h3>Sed mattis nunc</h3>
                        <p>Duis non efficitur nisi, sed justo. Maecenas sagittis semper.</p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="icon fa-laptop">
                        <h3>Porta ultricies</h3>
                        <p>Maecenas sagittis felis ac sagittis semper. Curabitur purus leo.</p>
                    </article>
                    <article class="icon fa-paper-plane">
                        <h3>Magna tellus</h3>
                        <p>Auctor orci eu dolor consectetur, interdum ullamcorper ante.</p>
                    </article>
                </section> 
    ';  

}
```

Widget JS

```
/*
    Widget JS
*/

    // Run Scripts
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            // Run scripts on widget page load
                widget_toggle();
                widget_sort();
                banner_button();                        

            // Open Media Upload Window  
                jQuery(document).on("click", ".upload_image_button", function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var $input_field = $(this).prev();
                    var custom_uploader = wp.media.frames.file_frame = wp.media({
                        title: 'Upload or Select an Image',
                        button: {
                            text: 'Add Image'
                        },
                        multiple: false
                    });
                    custom_uploader.on('select', function() {
                        var attachment = custom_uploader.state().get('selection').first().toJSON();
                        $input_field.val(attachment.url);
                    });
                    custom_uploader.open();
                });            

        });

    // Run scripts after widget saves

        jQuery(document).ajaxSuccess(function(e, xhr, settings) {
            widget_sort();
            banner_button();                     
        }); 

    // Hack to let us use js when widget is dragged in.

        jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete( function( event, XMLHttpRequest, ajaxOptions ) {

            // determine which ajax request is this (we're after "save-widget")
                var request = {}, pairs = ajaxOptions.data.split('&'), i, split, widget;
                for( i in pairs ) {
                    split = pairs[i].split( '=' );
                    request[decodeURIComponent( split[0] )] = decodeURIComponent( split[1] );
                }

                // only proceed if this was a widget-save request
                    if( request.action && ( request.action === 'save-widget' ) ) {
                        // locate the widget block
                            widget = jQuery('input.widget-id[value="' + request['widget-id'] + '"]').parents('.widget');

                        // trigger manual save, if this was the save request 
                        // and if we didn't get the form html response (the wp bug)
                            if( !XMLHttpRequest.responseText )
                                wpWidgets.save(widget, 0, 1, 0);

                    }

        }); 

/* *********************************************************************** */
// Functions
/* *********************************************************************** */

   // Make widget sortable
        function widget_sort() {

            jQuery( "#widgets-right .widget_sort" ).sortable({
                cursor: 'move'          
            });

            // Detect when widget is sorted
                jQuery( "#widgets-right .widget_sort" ).on('sortstop', function(e ,form) {

                    var widget = jQuery(this).closest(".widget").attr("id");

                    console.log('sorted');

                });    
        }         

    // Toggle widget options
        function widget_toggle() {

             jQuery(document).on( "click", '.widget_toggle header', function( e ) {

                var t       = jQuery( this ),
                    inner   = t.next( '.inner' );

                t.toggleClass('active');
                inner.toggleClass('active');
                e.preventDefault();
             });

        }

    // Handle the Button link
        function banner_button() {

            jQuery(document).on( "change", '.link_action', function() {

                var $t              = jQuery(this).val(),
                    $slide          = jQuery(this).closest( '.banner_slide' ),
                    $link_url       = $slide.find( '.link_url' ),
                    $link_post      = $slide.find( '.link_post' ),
                    $button_link    = $slide.find( '.button_link' );


                if ( $t == 'link_url' ) {

                    $link_url.show();
                    $link_post.hide();

                } else if ( $t == 'link_post' ) {

                            $link_post.show();
                            $link_url.hide();

                } else {

                    $button_link.hide();

                }


            });

        }
```

Customizer JS

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) { 

    $( document ).on( 'widget-added', function( event, widget ) {

        var $saveBtn = $( widget ).find( '.widget-control-save' );

        // let's check if the control for this widget is ready and hit apply 
            if ( $saveBtn.closest( '.control-section' ).is( ':visible' ) )
                $saveBtn.click();

    });

    // update the content of the widget....
        $( document ).on( 'widget-synced', function( e, widget ,form ) {

            var _widget = $( '#' + widget[0].id );

            if ( _widget.data( 'synced' ) != true ) {

                _widget.find( '.widget-content' ).html( form );
                _widget.data( 'synced', true ); 

            }

        });    


});
```

Comment: Adding dynamic fields inside of a widget form is very error prone because the JS will try to sync the fields in JS with the fields being returned by the PHP `form` method. As can be seen in the TinyMCE-enhanced Text widget and Media widgets in 4.8, I've found it preferable to put the fields outside of the normal widget container and then sync their values into a hidden input. In your case, this hidden input could have a JSON blob..

Comment: Thanks, can you show an example, I don't understand fully.

Comment: The examples are the Text widget and media widgets in core. Read more in the Make/Core posts:
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/23/addition-of-tinymce-to-the-text-widget/
https://make.wordpress.org/core/2017/05/26/media-widgets-for-images-video-and-audio/